# AWS DynamoDB: TypeError: translator.translateInput is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, adonis.js

Im using DynamoDB query on Adonis (Node.js)

Controller.php

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
...
...
...
async testing({params,response}){
   var table_name='testing8'
   var year = "2015"
   var title = "The Big New Movie"
   var dynamoDB_params = {
      TableName: table_name,
      Item:{
         "year": {
            S: year,
         },
         "title": {
            S: title,
         },
         "info": {
            M: {
               "plot": {
                  S: "Nothing happens at all."
               },
               "rating": {
                  N: "0"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   var data = AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient().put(dynamoDB_params)
   response.json(data)
}
```

error message:

> TypeError: translator.translateInput is not a function

Hardly find any example on google of having this error message. But seemingly translator.translateInput is out of aws-sdk? I am new to DynamoDB please enlighten me.